# Why do some rows in gtsummary output show OR=1 and CI containing 1 but have significant p-values?

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance

0

I am using gtsummary to create a table that merges univariate and multivariate regression results. Here's the code I'm using:

```
r2 <- tbl_regression(step.model, exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% 
  bold_labels() 

r1 <- dmtb11_v1 %>% tbl_uvregression(                         
  method = glm,                           
  y = status,                            
  method.args = list(family = binomial),  
  exponentiate = TRUE                     
)

tbl_merge(list(r2, r1))
```

[image]

The table is being generated successfully, but I noticed that some rows show an odds ratio (OR) of 1 with a confidence interval (CI) of 1.00-1.00, indicating significant p-values. However, an OR of 1 and a CI containing the value 1 should typically indicate non-significant p-values. Can someone explain this behavior?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: It's impossible to know without knowing more about the data and how it was fit. Some more information may be helpful to elucidate what may be wrong. As it stands, an OR of 1 means that the variable makes no difference on the outcome, which seems unlikely, but this could be due to how it was coded (a constant has been added for example) or could be because of something motivating the data to behave that way.

Comment: Could it be that the scale of the variables is such that the ORs appear to be 1 but are actually just really close to 1? This output only has two decimal points of precision, which may not be enough to display the actual effects and confidence intervals. So what looks like OR = 1 (1.00, 1.00) might actually be OR = 1.003 (1.001, 1.006). Try changing the precision of the output or rescale your predictors (e.g., from mg/dL to mg/mL).

Answer (score 3):

I looked up "thrombocyte count" and a normal count is from 150,000 to 450,000.  This is a strong indication that @Noah's comment is correct. You are doing the equivalent of measuring adult human height in milimeters.  One additional thrombocyte is going to make only a trivial difference. I would change this to "thousand per mm^3" (you could also change the unit of volume, but the smaller units of volume aren't very familiar).

For glucose, normal levels are 70 to 100 mg/dl, so scale might not be the problem. What were glucose levels in your sample?

You should also (if you haven't already) check for outliers and influential points. They don't, in my experience, usually cause this sort of problem, but I think that if you had outliers on both sides, they might cause problems like this. (And you should always check, anyway).